# reliably updating(importing) mysql database from another location

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is only updated on my development machine.  I'll import this  database to the production server .

Later on my development machine, I'll have to modify the database. and to reflect the changes I'll have to update the database on my production machine, obviously.

What is the ideal way of doing this ? The only way that comes to mind is to drop the tables and then reimport it, but that doesn't sound ideal. Is there a way to import just the changes?

Comment: Script the changes over time/version.

Comment: Ponies, can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Percona Toolkit has something to sync tables across servers:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-sync.html

I think this is your best bet or a dump and reload on the production server.

Joshua